# Как правильно использовать tax_query в wordpress

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Всем привет нужно сделать выборку постов пользовательской таксономии с конкретным id. (ID таксономии) Руководствуясь документацией на сайте https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-taksonomij его пример:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'people',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'bob'
    )
)
) );
```

я пытаюсь повторить, в моем случае имеем taxonomy - job_listing_category
post_type - job_listing и id конкретной категории для выборки постов к примеру 1743
итак код

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    [ 'tax_query ' =>
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
            'fields' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => '1743'
        ]
    ]
];

$q = new WP_Query( $args );
debug($q->posts);
```

И в этом случае получаю все посты из таксономии job_listing_category но 'terms' => '1743' не срабатывает. Вопрос почему так происходит?

Данные по таксономии беру из адресной строки - [скриншот](http://joxi.ru/xAeoW9SppEdOmy)

я же правильно выбрал данные?

Потом мне подсказали сделать иначе запрос в класс WP_Query выглядит следующим образом:

```
$args1['tax_query'][] = [
    'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => 1743
];
```

Таким образом срабатывает и отображается нужная категория, но это противоречит документации я в замешательстве помогите понять почему так происходит :)

Ну все что дальше идет после запроса WP_Query() нас не интересует поэтому код по сути такой:

```
function inpoland_job_categories_cb(){

    /**
 * Такой запрос не срабатывет
 */
$args1 = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => [
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => '4088',
    ],
];
/**
 * Запрос который мне подсказали
 */
$args2['tax_query'][] = [
    'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => '1743',
    'post_per_page' => 2
];


/**
 * Правильной запрос
 */
$args3 = [
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
            'fields' => 'id',
            'terms' => '1743',
        ]
    ],
    'post_per_page' => '20'
];

$q = new WP_Query( $args3 );
debug($q->posts); //просто вывод на экран

}
add_shortcode('inpoland_job_categories', 'inpoland_job_categories_cb');
```

Comment: Лучше дайте ответ на свой вопрос. И обратите внимание на то, что у kama тоже вложенный массив. Так что несоответсвия документации нет.

Comment: Да я ошибся сам